# apache redirect root results in recursion

Tags: apache, redirect, apache2

I'm attempting to direct all traffic to `http://foo.foo/` on my domain to a specific page on that domain `http://foo.foo/page/`. The [`mod-rewrite` docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/avoid.html) suggest using `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` for simple reidrects, but when I try that with the rule:

```
Redirect / http://foo.foo/page/
```

or

```
Redirect / /page/
```

I end up with an infinite recursion (the browser ends up with the url `http://page/page/page/page/page/page/....`).

Answer (score 1):

As I compiled the question, I came apon the answer - quite simple really (:

Firstly, the `Redirect` directive looks at the url **prefix**. If you use `/` it matches everything, hence the recursion.

Secondly, when using `RedirectMatch`, it matches your regex against **any** part of the path (or maybe any part after the domain specification?). Anyway, using `RedirectMatch /$` matches every path ending in `/` (eg: my `/page/`).

The solution was to use this:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /page/
```